# Drush 11 incompatible with drupal/recommended-project?

Tags: drush, 9

https://www.drush.org/latest/install/ indicates that Drush 10 is no longer supported. Drush 11 seems to be incompatible with drupal/recommended-project:9.* due to its dependency (via drupal/core-recommended:9.*) on symfony/http-client-contracts:2.5.0.

Is that intentional, or am I missing something?

Comment: `$ composer create-project drupal/recommended-project test && cd test && composer require drush/drush` gets me the latest Drush 11. 

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to update the dependencies using the `--with-all-dependencies` flag, or `-W`. You should be able to do it with this:

```
composer require drush/drush -W
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried that before posting. The conflict is not in Drush's dependencies. If you're not using drupal/recommended-project, you won't have this conflict. But the Drupal installation instructions say to use drupal/recommended-project, and version 9 of that requires version 2.5 of symfony/http-client-contracts, which is incompatible with Drush 11.

Comment: I realize that since this is not a Drush specific problem, it might not belong here. I guess the reason I posted it here is that Drush 10 is marked as unsupported, but unless I'm missing something, it's the only version that works with drupal/recommended-project 9.

Comment: I'm using drupal/recommended project with Drush 11 on two projects, so it must be compatible. Your conflict must be somewhere else. You should add the composer output to your original post.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. The command I had to use was a synthesis of both suggestions above: `composer require drush/drush drupal/core-recommended -W`

Comment: Great, glad you got it worked out.